# Hadoop Streaming Omitting Very Large Records

Tags: streaming, hadoop, out-of-memory, readline, bufferedreader

I have a hadoop streaming program where reader.readline() has an OutOfMemoryException if the line passed in is too large (over 20M or so).  Is there a way to tell hadoop to not pass in records that are over a certain size?  The records that are too large are 1 in a million.  I'd rather not use the skip bad record option...

I've also tried using this code http://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-java/issues/attachmentText?id=183&aid=-7134623167843514645&name=BoundedBufferedReader.java  instead of reader.readline(), but its too slow, I think because it reads in only one character at a time.

Comment: I added a gig of swap which seemed to alleviate the problem, though my original question still stands.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a problem with Hadoop, it's a problem with the way you are reading the line.

`reader.readline()` probably reads one character at a time because it needs to find out where the end of line is. Therefore, checking character by character probably isn't going to be much slower. You could read one character at a time, push it back into some sort of list or buffer. If it gets too long, ignore the line and move on. Once you see the newline character, you are good to go.